# Looking for AS3 event when MovieClip is initialised like AS2 onclipevent(load)

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

In AS2 there was an event onclipevent(load) that triggered when a movie clip was initialised on the stage. I have searched a lot but the only solution I can find for the same functionality in AS3 is to make a custom class for the movie clip. This is a bit overkill in my case as I only have one line of code to run and I'm trying to avoid lots of extra AS files in my project. I should note that my MovieClips are not dynamically added so events like Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE etc will not work.

Is there really no way to do onclipevent(load) in AS3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no AS2 style clip events in AS3. If you want to avoid making a custom class for your clip, you could put the initialization code in a function and call it immediately when you create the clip, like this:

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;
function onClipLoad(clip : MovieClip) : void
{
    // do onLoadStuff here
    clip.x = 100;
    clip.y = 10;
}

// call onClipLoad when the clip is created, either in code or via timeline
var myClip : MovieClip = new MyClip();
onClipLoad(myClip);
```

Even better, you could place this code on frame 1 of your MovieClip's timeline to automatically initialize instances of it:

```
var initialized : Boolean;
if(!initialized) {
   initialized = true;
   // do init code here
   x = 100;
   y = 10;
}
```

Comment: Ha! Wow that makes so much sense I'm surprised I was confused at all! Seems like I'm so used to AS2's quirks I didn't even think to just try the obvious solution! Thanks Mike